# Login into multisite

Tags: wagtail

I am looking for a way to share information about logged-in user between individual sites at Wagtail multisite.
By that I mean the possibility to log in on one site and by that be logged in on all the others.

Comment: Do your sites share a base domain, e.g. example.com, foo.example.com, bar.example.com? If so, logging into example.com should provide access to the 2 others, assuming the user has page permissions on all 3 sites. 

If the sites do not have a shared base domain, you may need to customize the admin login to set multiple cookies for the multiple sites (and to delete them all when logging out of any of the sites)